# Will it be a problem if I do not complete an ActionBlock

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to use action block to execute some tasks. My question is when the `CreateActionBlock()` method finishes, the `ActionBlock` is still processing the data. Since the method is returned and I do not have a way to call `actionBlock.Complete()`. Will it cause any problems if I run this `CreateActionBlock()` thousand times? Will there be thousand of actionBlocks forever in the memory or they will be GC'ed after the 5 inputs processed?

```
private static async Task Dequeue(string content)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The string is " + content);
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}

public static void CreateActionBlock()
{
    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(
        (e) => Dequeue(e),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 5,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
        });

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        actionBlock.Post(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [Does linking keep the linked block alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435787/does-linking-keep-the-linked-block-alive)

Comment: The answer to "will it cause any problems" is *probably* yes. The action block will work fine, and the GC will work fine, but your program will not know when it is safe to exit. So from a very broad perspective, fire-and-forget means you're ok with losing work. Which most programs are not ok with. But if you're OK with losing work when your program exits, then this will work.

Answer (score 3):

A dataflow block is eligible for garbage collection as soon as its input queue has been emptied, and it is currently idle. Below is an example that demonstrates this behavior:

```
var weakReference = InnerMethod();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {weakReference.IsAlive}");
}

WeakReference InnerMethod()
{
    var block = new ActionBlock<int>(n =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine($"Processed: {n}");
    });
    block.Post(1); block.Post(2); block.Post(3);
    return new WeakReference(block);
}
```

Output:

```xml
IsAlive: True
Processed: 1
IsAlive: True
IsAlive: True
Processed: 2
IsAlive: True
IsAlive: True
Processed: 3
IsAlive: False
IsAlive: False
IsAlive: False
IsAlive: False
IsAlive: False
```

([Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1zcRxG))